# How to convert Avro GenericRecord to a valid Json using while coverting timestamp fields from milliseconds to datetime?

Tags: avro

How to convert Avro GenericRecord to Json using while coverting timestamp fields from milliseconds to datetime?

Currently using Avro 1.8.2

```
    Timestamp tsp = new Timestamp(1530228588182l);
    Schema schema  = SchemaBuilder.builder()
            .record("hello")
            .fields()
            .name("tsp").type(LogicalTypes.timestampMillis().addToSchema(Schema.create(Schema.Type.LONG))).noDefault()
            .endRecord();
    System.out.println(schema.toString());

    GenericRecord genericRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
    genericRecord.put("tsp",tsp.getTime()); //Assume I cannot change this
    System.out.println(genericRecord.toString());
```

I tried using the function below but the result is same as `genericrecord.toString()`

```
public static String toJsonString(Schema schema, GenericRecord genericRecord) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
    writer.getData().addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimestampConversion());
    JsonEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, baos, false);
    writer.write(genericRecord, encoder);
    encoder.flush();
    return baos.toString();
}
```

Third Attempt

```
public static GenericRecord deserialize(final Schema schema, byte[] data) throws IOException {
        final GenericData genericData = new GenericData(){
            @Override
            public String toString(Object datum) {
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                // Since these types are not quoted and produce a malformed JSON string, quote it here.
                if (datum instanceof java.sql.Timestamp || datum instanceof java.sql.Time || datum instanceof java.sql.Date) {
                    return buffer.append("\"").append(datum).append("\"").toString();
                }
                return super.toString(datum);
            }
        };
        genericData.addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimestampConversion());
        genericData.addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimeConversion());
        try (final InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data)) {
            final Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(is, null);
            final DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema, schema, genericData);
            return reader.read(null, decoder);
        }
    }
```

Schema

```
{"type":"record","name":"tsp_name","fields":[{"name":"tsp","type":{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}}]}
```

Current Output

```
{"tsp":2018-06-28T23:29:48.182Z} // missing quotes so not a valid json
```

Expected Output

```
{"tsp": "2018-06-28T23:29:48.182Z"}
```

Comment: just edit my previous answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To change the projection you can extend the conversion to return a string for timestamp-millis logical type. The following code result in your expected output

```
import org.apache.avro.*;
import org.apache.avro.data.TimeConversions;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.*;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Main5 {
    public static void main(String [] args ) throws IOException {
        Timestamp tsp = new Timestamp(1530228588182L);
        String strSchema = "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"tsp_name\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"tsp\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"long\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"}}]}\n";
        Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(strSchema);
        System.out.println(new DateTime(tsp.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC));
        GenericRecord genericRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
        genericRecord.put("tsp",tsp.getTime()); //Assume I cannot change this
        System.out.println(genericRecord);
        System.out.println(deserialize(schema, toByteArray(schema , genericRecord)));
    }

    public static byte [] toByteArray(Schema schema, GenericRecord genericRecord) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
        writer.getData().addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimestampConversion());
        BinaryEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(baos, null);
        writer.write(genericRecord, encoder);
        encoder.flush();
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }


    public static GenericRecord deserialize(Schema schema, byte[] data) throws IOException {
        final GenericData genericData = new GenericData();
        genericData.addLogicalTypeConversion(new MyTimestampConversion());
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(is, null);
        DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema, schema, genericData);
        return reader.read(null, decoder);
    }

    public static class MyTimestampConversion extends Conversion<String> {
        public MyTimestampConversion() {
        }

        public Class<String> getConvertedType() {
            return String.class;
        }

        public String getLogicalTypeName() {
            return "timestamp-millis";
        }

        public String fromLong(Long millisFromEpoch, Schema schema, LogicalType type) {
            return (new DateTime(millisFromEpoch, DateTimeZone.UTC)).toString();
        }

        public Long toLong(String timestamp, Schema schema, LogicalType type) {
            return new Long(timestamp);
        }
    }
}
```

Output `{"tsp": "2018-06-28T23:29:48.182Z"}`
`

Comment: You can also use a Json encoder/decoder: `JsonDecoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, is)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first attempt is that the LogicalType information never leaves the schema, the GenericRecord just sees a long.

I suspect the 2nd attempt fails because it's writing json to the avro format, looking at [GenericDatumWriter](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericDatumWriter.java) the conversion is to write the base type (this is the same thing the avro-tools do when dumping data.)

Maybe you need a special case decoder to transform the timestamp to a string formatted the way you want?

Comment: I gave a third attempt. Now it looks so close but I am missing quotes so it is not a valid json. any suggestions?