# Writing Parquet/Avro GenericRecord to JSON while maintaining LogicalTypes

Tags: java, json, hadoop, avro, parquet

I am trying to write some Parquet records that contain LogicalTypes to JSON. I do this via `AvroParquetReader`, which gives me an Avro `GenericRecord`:

```java
GenericData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimeMillisConversion());

try (ParquetReader<GenericRecord> parquetReader =
    AvroParquetReader.<GenericRecord>builder(new LocalInputFile(this.path))
        .withDataModel(GenericData.get())
        .build()) {
    GenericRecord record = parquetReader.read();
    record.toString();
}
```

`record.toString()` produces:

```json
{"universe_member_id": 94639, "member_from_dt": 2001-08-31T00:00:00Z, "member_to_dt": 2200-01-01T00:00:00Z}
```

Notice that this is invalid JSON - the dates are correctly converted as per their `LogicalType`, but are not surrounded by quotes.

So instead I tried the `JsonEncoder`:

```java
GenericData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new TimeConversions.TimeMillisConversion()); //etc
OutputStream stringOutputStream = new StringOutputStream();

try (ParquetReader<GenericRecord> parquetReader =
    AvroParquetReader.<GenericRecord>builder(new LocalInputFile(this.path))
        .withDataModel(GenericData.get())
        .build()) {
    GenericRecord record = parquetReader.read();
    DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(record.getSchema());
    JsonEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(record.getSchema(), stringOutputStream);
    writer.write(record, encoder);
    encoder.flush();
}
```

but this doesn't convert the date fields at all and bakes the datatype into every record:

```json
{"universe_member_id":{"long":94639},"member_from_dt":{"long":999216000000000},"member_to_dt":{"long":7258118400000000}}
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
{"universe_member_id": 94639, "member_from_dt": "2001-08-31T00:00:00Z", "member_to_dt": "2200-01-01T00:00:00Z"}
```

How can I correctly write a `GenericRecord` to JSON?

Comment: I've been looking around for this as well - if you set `encoder.setIncludeNamespace(false);` it doesn't bake the datatypes of the fields into the JSON representation. This still doesn't fix the timestamp being cast to long though, so the output isn't that different from `toString`

Comment: this was also helpful for me (less code too): https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/19893471.html

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out, it looks like much less code which is exactly what I want. BTW that link appears to be from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982374.

Comment: @Ishnark I'd just like to thank you again, that answer you linked to worked for me.

Comment: Glad it worked for you too - have you by any chance had to figure out how to parse union types [null, someOtherLogicalType] and omit the key if its null?

Comment: @Ishnark I'm afraid I haven't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have indicated, the method `toString()` in class `GenericRecord` will give you a nearly valid JSON representation.

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/rdblue/avro-java/blob/master/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericData.java) of the `GenericData` class, the `GenericData.Record` `toString` method just invoke the `GenericData` `toString(Object)` method in its implementation.

If you want a valid JSON representation of the record, you can take that code and, with minimal modifications, obtain the information that you need.

For instance, we can define an utility class like the following:

```java
package stackoverflow.parquetavro;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.IdentityHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.apache.avro.LogicalType;
import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericContainer;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericEnumSymbol;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord;

public class GenericRecordJsonEncoder {

  Map<LogicalType, Function<Object, Object>> logicalTypesConverters = new HashMap<>();

  public void registerLogicalTypeConverter(LogicalType logicalType, Function<Object, Object> converter) {
    this.logicalTypesConverters.put(logicalType, converter);
  }

  public Function<Object, Object> getLogicalTypeConverter(Schema.Field field) {
    Schema fieldSchema = field.schema();
    LogicalType logicalType = fieldSchema.getLogicalType();
    return getLogicalTypeConverter(logicalType);
  }

  public Function<Object, Object> getLogicalTypeConverter(LogicalType logicalType) {
    if (logicalType == null) {
      return Function.identity();
    }

    return logicalTypesConverters.getOrDefault(logicalType, Function.identity());
  }

  public String serialize(GenericRecord value) {
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    serialize(value, buffer, new IdentityHashMap<>(128) );
    String result = buffer.toString();
    return result;
  }

  private static final String TOSTRING_CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_ERROR_TEXT =
      " \">>> CIRCULAR REFERENCE CANNOT BE PUT IN JSON STRING, ABORTING RECURSION <<<\" ";

  /** Renders a Java datum as <a href="http://www.json.org/">JSON</a>. */
  private void serialize(final Object datum, final StringBuilder buffer, final IdentityHashMap<Object, Object> seenObjects) {
    if (isRecord(datum)) {
      if (seenObjects.containsKey(datum)) {
        buffer.append(TOSTRING_CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_ERROR_TEXT);
        return;
      }
      seenObjects.put(datum, datum);
      buffer.append("{");
      int count = 0;
      Schema schema = getRecordSchema(datum);
      for (Schema.Field f : schema.getFields()) {
        serialize(f.name(), buffer, seenObjects);
        buffer.append(": ");
        Function<Object, Object> logicalTypeConverter = getLogicalTypeConverter(f);
        serialize(logicalTypeConverter.apply(getField(datum, f.name(), f.pos())), buffer, seenObjects);
        if (++count < schema.getFields().size())
          buffer.append(", ");
      }
      buffer.append("}");
      seenObjects.remove(datum);
    } else if (isArray(datum)) {
      if (seenObjects.containsKey(datum)) {
        buffer.append(TOSTRING_CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_ERROR_TEXT);
        return;
      }
      seenObjects.put(datum, datum);
      Collection<?> array = getArrayAsCollection(datum);
      buffer.append("[");
      long last = array.size()-1;
      int i = 0;
      for (Object element : array) {
        serialize(element, buffer, seenObjects);
        if (i++ < last)
          buffer.append(", ");
      }
      buffer.append("]");
      seenObjects.remove(datum);
    } else if (isMap(datum)) {
      if (seenObjects.containsKey(datum)) {
        buffer.append(TOSTRING_CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_ERROR_TEXT);
        return;
      }
      seenObjects.put(datum, datum);
      buffer.append("{");
      int count = 0;
      @SuppressWarnings(value="unchecked")
      Map<Object,Object> map = (Map<Object,Object>)datum;
      for (Map.Entry<Object,Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        serialize(entry.getKey(), buffer, seenObjects);
        buffer.append(": ");
        serialize(entry.getValue(), buffer, seenObjects);
        if (++count < map.size())
          buffer.append(", ");
      }
      buffer.append("}");
      seenObjects.remove(datum);
    } else if (isString(datum)|| isEnum(datum)) {
      buffer.append("\"");
      writeEscapedString(datum.toString(), buffer);
      buffer.append("\"");
    } else if (isBytes(datum)) {
      buffer.append("{\"bytes\": \"");
      ByteBuffer bytes = ((ByteBuffer) datum).duplicate();
      writeEscapedString(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.decode(bytes), buffer);
      buffer.append("\"}");
    } else if (((datum instanceof Float) &&       // quote Nan & Infinity
        (((Float)datum).isInfinite() || ((Float)datum).isNaN()))
        || ((datum instanceof Double) &&
        (((Double)datum).isInfinite() || ((Double)datum).isNaN()))) {
      buffer.append("\"");
      buffer.append(datum);
      buffer.append("\"");
    } else if (datum instanceof GenericData) {
      if (seenObjects.containsKey(datum)) {
        buffer.append(TOSTRING_CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_ERROR_TEXT);
        return;
      }
      seenObjects.put(datum, datum);
      serialize(datum, buffer, seenObjects);
      seenObjects.remove(datum);
    } else {
      // This fallback is the reason why GenericRecord toString does not
      // generate a valid JSON representation
      buffer.append(datum);
    }
  }

  // All these methods are also copied from the GenericData class source

  private boolean isRecord(Object datum) {
    return datum instanceof IndexedRecord;
  }

  private Schema getRecordSchema(Object record) {
    return ((GenericContainer)record).getSchema();
  }

  private Object getField(Object record, String name, int position) {
    return ((IndexedRecord)record).get(position);
  }

  private boolean isArray(Object datum) {
    return datum instanceof Collection;
  }

  private Collection getArrayAsCollection(Object datum) {
    return (Collection)datum;
  }

  private boolean isEnum(Object datum) {
    return datum instanceof GenericEnumSymbol;
  }

  private boolean isMap(Object datum) {
    return datum instanceof Map;
  }

  private boolean isString(Object datum) {
    return datum instanceof CharSequence;
  }

  private boolean isBytes(Object datum) {
    return datum instanceof ByteBuffer;
  }

  private void writeEscapedString(CharSequence string, StringBuilder builder) {
    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
      char ch = string.charAt(i);
      switch(ch){
        case '"':
          builder.append("\\\"");
          break;
        case '\\':
          builder.append("\\\\");
          break;
        case '\b':
          builder.append("\\b");
          break;
        case '\f':
          builder.append("\\f");
          break;
        case '\n':
          builder.append("\\n");
          break;
        case '\r':
          builder.append("\\r");
          break;
        case '\t':
          builder.append("\\t");
          break;
        default:
          // Reference: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.1.0/
          if((ch>='\u0000' && ch<='\u001F') || (ch>='\u007F' && ch<='\u009F') || (ch>='\u2000' && ch<='\u20FF')){
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(ch);
            builder.append("\\u");
            for(int j = 0; j < 4 - hex.length(); j++)
              builder.append('0');
            builder.append(hex.toUpperCase());
          } else {
            builder.append(ch);
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this class you can register converters for the logical types that you need. Consider the following example:

```java
GenericRecordJsonEncoder encoder = new GenericRecordJsonEncoder();
// Register as many logical types converters as you need
encoder.registerLogicalTypeConverter(LogicalTypes.timestampMillis(), o -> {
  final Instant instant = (Instant)o;
  final String result = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(instant);
  return result;
});

String json = encoder.serialize(genericRecord);
System.out.println(json);
```

This will provide you the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was really hoping that Parquet would contain a library to do this automatically, but if this is the best answer then so be it.

Comment: I'm going to give it a few more days so that I can keep looking into it, but will select this answer if it's still the best.

Comment: You are welcome Ben. Of course, please, wait until you consider necessary, I hope you get a better answer. Please, be aware that I have worked with Avro previously, but never have this requirement, so it is possible that other solutions exist.

Comment: Ben, I provide you also a couple of links to libraries that seem promising. In any case, please, be aware that these libraries maybe will no give you the logical type required conversion because this kind of conversion, the actual value presented, is very specific (think, for instance, which timestamp format, which string literal, should be used to display a timestamp millis). In any case, I hope it helps. I will try to investigate it on my own tomorrow.

Comment: Sadly neither of those libraries support LogicalTypes; dates are printed as Longs.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that Ben. I think the use case is quite specific, this is why I also proposed you a custom implementation based on ```GenericData``` ```toString(Object)``` method. I modified my original answer to make it more versatile and reusable. In any case, I hope somebody gives you a better solution.

Comment: Thank you very much @BenWatson. I'm sorry no one gave you a better answer. Hope at least the one I gave you helps you with your problem.

Comment: Nice Ben, I'm happy to hear it. Thank you very much.